# add property and method to java class in runtime

Tags: groovy

I am trying to add static method to existing `java.util.Random` class in Java.

```
Random.metaClass.private.static.instance = new Random()
Random.metaClass.public.static.nextInt = { instance.nextInt() }

Random.nextInt() // MissingMethodException
```

However when I do it like this I get `MissingMethodException`.
What is wrong?

Comment: Hmm - I can't find any evidence that the `public`/`private` syntax you're using there is actually valid.  Not saying it *isn't* valid, just that I can't find any prior art....

Comment: indeed. It seems `static` does not work either for the property and only for closures... tsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be quite interesting... If you code this:

```
Random.metaClass.static.nextInt = { (new Random()).nextInt() }

Random.nextInt()
```

You get a `StackOverflowError`. However, if you change the name of the static method, it works:

```
Random.metaClass.static.nextInteger = { (new Random()).nextInt() }

Random.nextInteger()
```

Yes, public/private does not work.